# subtabs are not opening for links in a iframe inside a vf page

Tags: visualforce-component, subtab-apps

I am not able to open subtabs for the links which are on the iframe embedded inside a vf page in sales console , getEnclosingprimarytabId() not able to get the primary tab id .

Comment: It may help if you include some of the code in your question

Comment: there are some links on a vf page used output link,and i have kept these links vf page on another vf page using iframe , but when i used sforce.getenclosingprimarytabid() method it is not able to get the id of primary tab. because it is in the i frame thats my issue

Comment: sry i can not include the code

Comment: Then do please try to post simplified code which replicates your problem. This can either help you debug, or make it easier for us to understand the problem and what your code is doing.

Comment: got solution for my issue by using window.parent.sforce.getEnclosingprimarytabId() .thanq all

Comment: Kiran do please post that as an answer. That way it's more clear to other users looking for an answer in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got solution for my issue by using

```
window.parent.sforce.getEnclosingprimarytabId();
```

u can get the id of your primary tab id and can open the subtab using the id